# Add two values to create a sum

Tags: php

I have two PHP functions and they both return a number value. I would like to add both these values together to create a sum.

```
<?= getTrails(); ?>   <?= getGlades(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you considered using addition ?

Comment: Yes, i would rule out multiplication, division and subtraction.

Comment: I actually do not know much about php. any help would be awesome.

Comment: Think back to math class and the special symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the output of both functions is a number, it's as easy as

```
<?= getTrails() + getGlades(); ?>
```

Comment: deleted it completely

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<?php echo getTrails() + getGlades(); ?>
```

using `<?=` is not a good practice

Comment: In php.ini file "short_open_tag" should be enabled for <?= to work and in recent versions of PHP this is disabled by default. It that case you can get errors.

Comment: Short echo syntax isn't tied to short open tag any more (since php 5.4) and can't be disabled (and for that isn't disabled by default) in php.ini, so using it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the output to variables and then add the variables to get the sum.

```
<?php 
$firstNumber = getTrails(); 
$secondNumber = getGlades(); 

$sum = $firstNumber + $secondNumber;

//NOW PRINT THE SUM 
echo $sum; 

?>
```

Comment: it will display a value if his functions getTrails and getGlades are already returning numbers.

Comment: yes actually when i wrote this comment echo $sum; was missing.. no prob now.